# Android emulator has incorrect window placement

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I launch Android Emulator, the phone "background" appears to be the correct size, however the phone display (pink in the picture) is incorrectly sized and incorrectly placed.

When I click on the black display, the clicks register as if the pink display was properly overlayed (i.e., clicking in the lower-left of the black display would open the calling app).

Is there a way to fix this? I can only imagine it's related to HIDPI issues. Output of `xdpyinfo | grep -B2 dots`:

`screen #0:
  dimensions:    3840x2160 pixels (443x249 millimeters)
  resolution:    220x220 dots per inch`

On Ubuntu 17.04, i3.

[image: Screenshot here.]

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution that worked for me.
find libstdc++.so.6 sdk/emulator/lib64/ and sdk/emulator/lib64/ , rename it to libstdc++.so.6.bak.